# JSF GrapicImage component doesn´t render alternative text in the right way

Tags: html, jsf

I have a problem with a JSF graphicImage component in the Internet Explorer Browser 7 and 8.

If no picture was found on picture.iconPath, the IE 7 and IE 8 rendered a red X (default symbol for a missing image) and render the text, which was value of the attribute "alt":

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{bean.pictures}" var="picture">

    <h:graphicImage value="#{picture.iconPath}"
         alt="#{textemap[picture.alternativeKey]}" title="#{textmap[picture.alternativeKey]}" />
</a4j:repeat>
```

Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome don´t have any problem with the solution with this JSF component, if they don´t find a icon. They show only the given text for the attribute "alt".

How is it possible to solve this problem with the IE 7 and IE 8? Is it resolvable  with this kind of JSF code?

Thanks for help!
Marwief

Comment: Are you implying that you don't face this problem when you use a plain HTML page `test.html` with a hardcoded `<img>` element instead of having JSF to generate that HTML? This is namely not a JSF problem, but a HTML+browser-specific problem. You should forget JSF for now and fiddle around with plain HTML. Once you get that HTML straight (at least, theoretically ...), then you just have to write JSF code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML.

Comment: You are right, but this way of solution isn´t acceptable for my jsf project and my customer. So i need perhaps a JSF component.

Comment: It looks like that you're missing my point (and the point of JSF). The statement in your question's title is namely completely wrong. It's namely the webbrowser who doesn't interpret it in the right way. You would have had exactly the same problem when having a plain HTML page (also when having any other MVC framework than JSF producing the same HTML output).

Comment: OK but how can i solve this problem? I have complete my jsf code.

Comment: _Note: Internet Explorer (prior version 9) displays the value of the alt attribute as a tooltip, when mousing over the image. This is NOT the correct behavior, according to the HTML specification._ [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp)

Comment: What BalusC means is, when you press F12 key(go to webTools) and look for the `<img>` tag in your DOM and see something like `<img src="path/myPic.png" alt="some text" title="some text">` then you should look for help somewhere else. It's not JSF relevant.